# Altium -- how to link multiple real parts to a library component for supplier live links?

Tags: altium, bom

I have an interesting use case for the Altium Supplier Live Links feature: I have several library components that I've made as one schematic component/footprint, but requires two real parts.

An example, you ask? Let's say I have several different pin headers that are integer multiples of a common part (say 4 pins, 8 pins, 12 pins). To keep the BoM count low, I buy just the 4-pin variety, and populate the 8/12/16 etc. pin headers with multiple 4-pin headers.

Is there a way to tell Altium that a single component actually requires 2 (or more) parts to be ordered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having come back around to this question a few times in the last few days, I've come up with two possible approaches:

1. Convert the single part into multiple parts, and place as necessary in the schematics. This accounts for all parts in the BoM but comes at the disadvantage of having to manage n times as many parts in your design (where n is the number of parts that you split into.
2. Edit the BoM by hand before it gets used. While very effective and much simpler, this route should horrify you for a number of good reasons.

May this help someone in the future. Also, for the record: I'm using Altium 15.1, in case this answer becomes stale sometime in the future.

Comment: I would say that the 'proper' way to do this is to manage it outside Altium. You will always have to make decisions at the build stage regarding what is cheaper for you and optimizing the build. (ie do I buy a reel of 10k 5% resistors for this one part instance, or should I sub a 10k 1% which the board has a bunch of) Your BOM should contain the BEST information so that if the build parameters change, you can re-optimize your BOM for manufacturing without having to go back into Altium to futz with the design.